# x-forward-for on tomcat 5.5.25

Tags: tomcat, http-headers, tomcat5.5

I am working on getting x-forward-for to work on tomcat 5.5.25, I know a patch has gone out for Tomcat 6.0.24, but we can't upgrade our tomcat version right now.  So I did some digging into the Tomcat 6.0.24 and found the RemoteIPValve.class(the class that implements x-forward-for) is located in catalina.jar.  My question is has anybody ever taken catalina.jar from a new version of tomcat and copied over to an older version of Tomcat?  My plan is to do just that, take the new catalina.jar and drop it in our 5.5.25 version.  I just wanted to see if anybody had already tried something like this and had success.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that a backport is available for Tomcat 5.5. All details (jar, sources and svn) are here : http://code.google.com/p/xebia-france/wiki/RemoteIpValve#Install_/_Download .

Cyrille (Xebia)